# Perl - Best practices when sending blocks to subs

Tags: perl

I'm a big fan of functional programming, so when I discovered block references in Perl I started using them a lot.

However, the functions I've written that take blocks as arguments are written in this style:

```
sub mygrep (&@) {
    my $code = shift;
    my @result;
    foreach $_ (@_) {
        push(@result, $_) if &$code;
    }
    @result;
}
```

(From http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes)

In essence, most of my functions set `$_` in order for the code block to gain access to data in my sub. I guess my question can be split into three subquestions:

1. Are there some major pitfalls in this approach?
2. Is it a better idea to `local`ize `$_` before setting it?
3. Should i use partially applied functions instead?

I'm still a Perl newbie so any answers and suggestions are appreciated - thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Are there some major pitfalls in this approach?

1. `my $_;` in view of the block will hide your changes to package variable `$_`. There's nothing you can do about that from inside of `mygrep`.
2. `&$code` is very special. You want `&$code()` or `$code->()` instead.
3. Changing `$_` will change the arguments passed to `mygrep`. That's undesirable here.

> 2. Is it a better idea to localize $_ before setting it?

`for` provides much better localisation that `local`, but it also provides aliasing that's undesirable here.

> 3. Should i use partially applied functions instead?

I don't know what that means.

---

Fixed:

```
sub mygrep (&@) {
    my $code = shift;
    my @result;
    for (@_) {
       # Create copy so $_ can be modified safely.
       for (my $s = $_) {
          push @result, $_ if $code->();
       }
    }

    return @result;
}
```

---

That said, I think `mygrep` is kind pointless, since `map`+`grep` already does what you want more easily. Compare

```
mygrep { if ($_ % 2) { ++$_; 1 } else { 0 } } LIST
```

with

```
map { $_+1 } grep { $_ % 2 } LIST
```

You can even merge the `map` and `grep`.

```
map { $_ % 2 ? $_+1 : () } LIST
```

Answer (score 5):

In the code you have written:

```
sub mygrep (&@) {
    my $code = shift;
    my @result;
    foreach $_ (@_) {
        push(@result, $_) if &$code;
    }
    @result;
}
```

The `foreach` loop is implicitly localizing the `$_` variable on every loop iteration.  It is perfectly safe (and the fastest way to get values into `$_` properly).

The only nit that I have with the code above is that every time `&$code` is executed, it has access to the source argument list, which could cause a bug.  You could rewrite the code as follows:

```
sub mygrep (&@) {
    my $code = shift;
    my @result;
    foreach $_ (splice @_) {
        push(@result, $_) if &$code;  # @_ is empty here
    }
    @result;
}
```

Here are a few other ways you could write that function:

```
sub mygrep (&@) {
    my ($code, @result) = shift;
    &$code and push @result, $_ for splice @_;
    @result
}

sub mygrep (&@) {
    my $code = shift;
    # or using grep in our new grep:
    grep &$code, splice @_
}
```

Each of these examples provides an aliased `$_` to its subroutine, with proper localization.

If you are interested in higher order functions, I'd encourage you to take a look at my module [List::Gen](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aGen) on CPAN, which provides dozens of higher order functions for manipulating both real and lazy lists.

```
use List::Gen;

my $list = filter {$_ % 2} <1..>;

# as a lazy array:
say "@$list[0 .. 5]"; # 1 3 5 7 9 11

# as an object:
$list->map('**2')->drop(100)->say(5); # 40401 41209 42025 42849 43681

zip('.' => <a..>, <1..>)->say(5);  # a1 b2 c3 d4 e5
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about List::Gen! CPAN is so vast, it can be hard to find the good parts sometimes...

Answer (score 4):

How about using `$code->($arg)`?

```
sub mygrep (&@) {
    my $code = shift;
    my @result;
    foreach my $arg (@_) {
        push(@result, $arg) if $code->( $arg);
    }
    @result;
}
```

I haven't tested it but I would assume this would work, and it would let you pass additional arguments to `$code`.

Updated: this looked fun so I went ahead and tested it. It works just fine, see below (I intensely dislike prototypes, so I removed it, especially as it kept complaining about @a not being an array ref ;--(

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub mygrep {
    my $code = shift;
    my @result;
    foreach my $arg (@_) {
        push(@result, $arg) if $code->( $arg);
    }
    @result;
}

my @a= ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
print mygrep( sub { return shift() % 2 }, @a), "\n";
```

And of course the main fun with this line of thinking is also to generate the code;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub mygrep {
    my $code = shift;
    my $filter= shift;
    my @result;
    foreach my $arg (@_) {
        push(@result, $arg) if $code->( $arg);
    }
    @result;
}

my @a= ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
print mygrep( mod_filter( 3), @a), "\n"; 
print mygrep( mod_filter( 4), @a), "\n"; 

sub mod_filter
  { my( $filter)= @_;
    return sub { ! (shift() % $filter) };
  }
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm thinking of doing; I've written some functions that look like what you would find in List::MoreUtils, where it's pretty natural to mimick the syntax of built-ins like grep and map.

 For those functions I think I will keep using $_, but for my other functions I think $code->($arg) is the way to go :)

Comment: from a readability POV, I am not a fan of the form `&$code`, it doesn't say "function call" to. So I would write it `$code->()`, but that's probably a personal preference.

Comment: readability yes, but when placed at the center of a loop, `&$code` is significantly faster than `$code->()` since it avoids localizing `@_` to an empty list on each loop iteration.

Comment: @Eric Strom fair enough, you're right. I still don't like it ;--)

Comment: Re "especially as it kept complaining about @a not being an array ref", that would only have occurred if you changed `@` to `\@` in the prototype.

Comment: @Eric Strom, if speed is need that bad, use XS's multicall.

Comment: @ikegami => agreed, but short of resorting to C, I view a properly setup `&$code` call to be as close as you can get to multicall from Perl code.  I need to spend more time getting familiar with XS, as I have a feeling I can speed up a number of my list processing functions.  Do you know of any tutorials or good code to read related to writing grep like functions in XS?

Comment: XS functions can have prototypes, and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlcall.html#LIGHTWEIGHT-CALLBACKS supposedly explains MULTICALL

Answer (score 3):

It's absolutely better to localize `$_`. The subref can modify the value of `$_`, and those changes will propagate into the calling function. This isn't a problem in the `mygrep()` case, but could be in others.